# Kernel mode clock_gettime()

Tags: linux, timer, kernel, posix

I'm trying to use the POSIX clock functions in the kernel but the compiler keeps giving me the error: error: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_gettime’

```
long __timer_end(struct timespec start_time)
{
    struct timespec end_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, &end_time);
    return(end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec);

}

struct timespec __timer_start(void)
{
    struct timespec start_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE, &start_time);
    return start_time;
}
```

The functions are defined in `<linux/posix_clock.h>` as part of structure called `posix_clock_operations` and there are a pair of functions, `posix_clock_register()` and `posix_clock_unregister()`.  The comments lead one to believe that these functions will populate the `posix_clock_operations` structure.  I've implemented both in my init and exit functions hoping that their presence would magically make the forward declarations for `clock_gettime()` appear, but it doesn't.

Does anyone know what I need to do to make this one function work?  Do I really need to define all my own functions an populate `posix clock_operations`?

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Comment: `clock_gettime()` is defined in `time.h`. Are you referring to this, or to the actual `clock_get_time()` (http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/clock_get_time.html) ?

Comment: Hi @John. In the kernel header `<linux/time.h>` the functions are not declared, just the structures and IDs etc.

Comment: I was referring to `time.h`, not `linux/time.h`. The former actually defines `extern int clock_gettime (clockid_t __clock_id, struct timespec *__tp)`.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but time.h is not in the kernel tree.  I think I've figured it out now though.  There is no such function in the kernel.  There is however `current_kernel_time()` which is a nsec granularity timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is no `clock_gettime()` in the kernel however there is a nsec resolution clock called `current_kernel_time()`.  So rewriting my timer looks like this:

```
long timer_end(struct timespec start_time)
{
    struct timespec end_time = current_kernel_time();
    return(end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec);
}

struct timespec timer_start(void)
{
    return current_kernel_time();
}
```

It seems to work fine, but a higher performance version of the same suitable for ns granular performance testing looks like this:

```
long timer_end(struct timespec start_time)
{
    struct timespec end_time;
    getrawmonotonic(&end_time);
    return(end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec);
}

struct timespec timer_start(void)
{
    struct timespec start_time;
    getrawmonotonic(&start_time);
    return start_time;
}
```

Thanks for the comments and pointers.

Pete

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in answer by pjenney58, you can use `current_kernel_time()`, but do keep in mind that it gives you the "wallclock" time (in HZ accuracy), which is not recommended if you want to profile time taken by some kernel code - simply because it'll also consider time spent in suspended mode. To profile timing in kernel code there is a kernel equivalent of userland `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)` viz. `do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime()` which is defined as a macro in `timekeeping.h`. It takes pointer to `struct timespec` as an argument in which monotonic clock time is returned in sec and nsec accuracy.